# Why is this Debug.Assert skipped?

Tags: c#, assertions

I have the following code:

```
Debug.Assert(model.OrganizationId != null, "model.OrganizationId != null");
var orgId = model.OrganizationId.Value;
```

Yet the `Debug.Assert` line is grayed out, and when I hover over it, I get the message:

> Method invocation is skipped. Compiler will not generate method
>   invocation because method is conditional, or is partial method without
>   implementation.

My IDE is in `Debug` mode and I see nothing else unusual. Why is this assert being skipped? I am not too concerned with `OrganizationId` being null, as it is marked as `Required` on the model, but I am concerned that a very normal looking `Debug.Assert` is being skipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debug.Assert is marked with this attribute.

```
[System.Diagnostics.Conditional("DEBUG")]
```

That means this method is compiled when you have the "DEBUG" constant defined in your project configuration.

Note that this is irrelevant to release or debug build mode. But by default debug configuration has "DEBUG" constant defined.

In order to fix this goto your project settings, build section, make sure configuration is set to Debug. Then tick the option "define DEBUG constant".

Comment: The config is set to Debug and the  "define DEBUG constant" option is ticked. I did have the build config set to RELEASE before, but everything looks right for the debug config now. The only conditional compile symbol explicitly defined is `NETCOREAPP2_0`. Other `Debug.Assert`s are OK and not blanked out. Maybe I should just restart VS again. Thanks.

Comment: great. so did the problem go away? the problem should go away by now or try restarting visual studio.

Comment: Restarting did the trick, thanks. Silly of me not to think of it, but I'm really busy testing and that wasn't bothering me. I accepted because if it wasn't just a VS quirk, your answer would have been dead on.